# ArcPad 10 Studio, from form to vbscript back to form

Tags: arcpad, vbscript

There is very little documentation on using vbscript within a form. Any help with syntax for ArcPad 10 would be appreciated.

Within my subroutine, I want to grab some numerical data entered in a control box on the form. Will this Set command grab the data that was input and assign it to the variable el1?

```
Sub getdata
Dim el1
Set el1 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element1")
End Sub
```

To bring data from the vbscript back to a control box on the form, assuming I have calculations done correctly for "scoreA"

### EDITFORM.Pages.Item("Results").Controls.Item("sumEl").Additem scoreA, scoreA

Getting very close.  Just need to get the data from the script back to the form. The above command line gives a runtime error "Class Doesn't Support Automation"

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working. Here is the whole script

```
Sub findelement
Dim el1, el2, el3, el4, el5, el6, el7, el8, el9, el10, el11, el12, el13, el14, el15, el16, scoreA, scoreB, calc

el1 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element1")
el2 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element2")
el3 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element3")
el4 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element4")
el5 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element5")
el6 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element6")
el7 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element7")
el8 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page4").Controls.Item("element8")
el9 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element9")
el10 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element10")
el11 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element11")
el12 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element12")
el13 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element13")
el14 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element14")
el15 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element15")
el16 = EDITFORM.Pages.Item("page5").Controls.Item("element16")

Dim c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16, Counter

For Counter = 1 to 16

If "x" = Eval("el" & Counter) Then
    execute "el" & Counter & " = 0"
    execute "c" & Counter & " = 0"
Else 
    execute "c" & Counter & " = 1"
End If
Next

'do math
scoreA = CInt(el1) + CInt(el2) + CInt(el3) + CInt(el4) + CInt(el5) + CInt(el6) + CInt(el7) + CInt(el8) + CInt(e9) + CInt(el10) + CInt(el11) + CInt(el12) + CInt(el13) + CInt(el14) + CInt(el15) + CInt(el16)
scoreB = CInt(c1) + CInt(c2) + CInt(c3) + CInt(c4) + CInt(c5) + CInt(c6) + CInt(c7) + CInt(c8) + CInt(c9) + CInt(c10) + CInt(c11) + CInt(c12) + CInt(c13) + CInt(c14) + CInt(c15) + CInt(c16)
calc = CDbl(scoreA) / CDbl(scoreB)
'vbscript assumes these are strings and appends them, to get the sum like you want cast them to a double (CDbl) or integer (CInt)

'Return calculated data to form......
EDITFORM.Pages("Results").Controls("sumEl").Value = (scoreA)
EDITFORM.Pages("Results").Controls("scoreB").Value = (scoreB)
EDITFORM.Pages("Results").Controls("calc").Value = (calc)

End Sub
```